# Is homosexuality genetic or can it be unlearned in one of those (christian) camps

Tags: psychology, physiology, gender, sexuality

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is homosexuality innate?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/564/is-homosexuality-innate)

I suppose I was trying to be tad too PC earlier. I've seen quite a few anti-gay person saying that homosexuality is something that is learned and can be unlearned so to speak. To my understanding some people even offer courses or camps for the very act. Is there any research base for this or is unlearning homosexuality just about suppressing it?

Edit: [Actually this question seems to answer my question.](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/564/is-homosexuality-innate)

Comment: Did you mean homosexuality? I think that the answer could differ (i.e. it *could be* that everybody is heterosexual genetically, but can then become homosexual, in which case heterosexuality would be genetic, but homosexuality would not)

Comment: How is this a notable claim to be skeptical of?

Comment: There are examples of twins who even when brought up in different environments tend to have the same "orientation". That being said, I often wonder the same thing.. 
However, perhaps a "notable" claim would be whether such a thing could be tested. i.e. will it ever be possible to definitively predict a persons orientation at birth?

Comment: This should probably go on [Biology SE](http://biology.stackexchange.com/)